# Feed values into Crop Node (Left, Right, Top and Bottom)

Tags: node-editor

I am a noob at doing this, as I started very recently.
I tried cropping every frame in a video file to my mouse cursor. So, I searched up the Track Position Node and tracked the position of my cursor slowly moving.

Then, I made a Math Node tried outputting variables for my Crop Node's Left, Right, Top and Bottom values. However, there are no input nodes other than Image.

Is there any way I can feed a value output into the Crop Node's Left Right, Top and Bottom?

[image: Image of me trying to feed values]

Comment: I thought it could be done with drivers but apparently not

Answer (score 0):

**QUICK UPDATE**

Found a workaround, just used an array of nodes that had x and y inputs
[image: yes]

Going to crop manually later using another crop node